# How can i delete a file from document directory using the bar button item using objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create a Bar button item (trash can) using storyboard.App crashes when i try to delete a file from document directory on button action. Here is code so far:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *deleteCsv;



-(void)deleteCsv:(id)sender{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileDataString4];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    if (success) {
        UIAlertView *removedSuccessFullyAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations:" message:@"Successfully removed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [removedSuccessFullyAlert show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not delete file -:%@ ",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Comment: Whenever you post a question about a crash or error you must include the following in your question ([edit] your question, do not post comments): 1 - the complete and exact error message. 2 - Point out the exact line of code causing the error.

Comment: @Alivajorg What is fileDataString4?

Comment: Contain the string of the file i want to delete @aNa12

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check first whether file exist at path or not with following code,

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:<your file path>]])
{
    //Delete your file
}
```

By following this you will be able to handle the crash if it is occuring because of file nonexistence